# Getting dataFields of DataGridColumn into ArrayCollection

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, arraycollection, datagridcolumn, datafield

I have a DataGrid with 3 DataGridColumns. All 3 of them have separate dataFields.

I need to get the datafields into an ArrayCollection and pass it to a funciton. I dont want to hard code the ArrayCollection.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var dataFieldCollection : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
for each (dataGridColumn : DataGridColumn in dataGrid.columns){
 dateFieldCollection.addItem(dataGridColumn.dateField);
}
```

This is psuedo code I wrote in the browser.